# How do I set and load NSUserDefaults in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I have:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let name = defaults.stringForKey("userNameKey") {
        println(name)
    }
```

In the applicationWillTerminate I have:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("Coding Explorer", forKey: "userNameKey")
```

But upon application load(which i've closed and reopened several times on the iphone simulator), it does not print. Any clue why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be better to use debugger to see whether or not your code invoke the following method `applicationWillTerminate`

Before we read or write data from NSUserDefaults, we must first get a reference to the NSUserDefaults class.

```
let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

For further information:

Once we have the reference saved to a constant, we can write data to it. You will be defining both the value and the key name to store the data.

```
prefs.setValue("Berlin", forKey: "userCity")
```

> //This code saves the value "Berlin" to a key named "userCity".

More information could be found in the following link: http://www.myswiftjourney.me/2014/10/01/simple-persistent-storage-using-nsuserdefaults/

Comment: So what you're saying is, that I don't need both instantiations of "defaults" in my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("Coding Explorer", forKey: "userNameKey")
defaults.synchronize()
```

Comment: i was told not to use synchronize in ios8 and after in this article, would you say it's true? http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/

Comment: Right, but in your case you cannot wait for automatic sync because your closing your app before it gets a chance to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to synchronize after writing to userdefaults...

i think this is for swift !?

```
defaults.synchronize()
```

in objective-c it s

```
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/ this guy said not to use synchronize in and after ios 8, would you concur?

Comment: hm, never heard of that... why not sync? have you just tried it? don t you want to be ios7 compatible anyways? there are still many users on ios7...

Comment: just read it, i do call synchronize in my app a lot and it s not slow at all... how can a simple call slow down an app? bet if you call it, you will achieve what you want...